# QTableView - faulty redraw with row selections

Tags: qt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm trying to put together a simple table that shows my model's data. I need row selection behaviour so I set:

```
self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
```

All is good until I implement `selectionChanged()` which causes the redraw to get a bit confused every time a row is selected (cell's dont' seem to update their selection state). Here is some test code that causes the problem for me:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class Item( QStandardItem ):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( Item, self).__init__( parent )
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("colour.png")

    #def data(self, role=Qt.UserRole + 1):
        #'''with this method in place the cells get a checkbox and are not selectable'''
        #return 'test'


class Model (QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( Model, self).__init__( parent )
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        self.init_data()

    def init_data(self):
        for row in range(0, 15):
            for col in range(0, 10):
                col_item = Item( '%s, %s' % (row, col) )
                self.setItem(row, col, col_item)

class TableView( QTableView ):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( TableView, self).__init__( parent )
        model = Model()
        self.setModel(model)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        print selected

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    table = TableView()
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm also a bit confused about why the cell's all get a checkbox and become un-selectable if the `data()` method is implemented in the `QStandardItem`. Can somebody please help?

Cheers,
frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the `QTableView`s `selectionChanged`. That is (probably) used internally by the view and you prevent that. I am not sure why you would want to do that. You should use the `selectionChanged` signal of the `selectionModel()` for the view if you want to do custom things when the selection changes.

But if you insist on overriding `selectionChanged` on `TableView` at least call the parents function too, so that view could do its work:

```
class TableView( QTableView ):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        super( TableView, self).__init__( parent )
        model = Model()
        self.setModel(model)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        print selected
        super(TableView, self).selectionChanged(selected, deselected)
```

**But**, you don't need to and you really shouldn't subclass a `QTableView` just to set a few properties. You can do that for an instance. Actually, all your sub-classes are unnecessary. You could write that code like this:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    # create model
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['a', 'b', 'c'])

    # fill data
    for row in range(15):
        model.appendRow([QStandardItem('%d, %d' % (row, col)) for col in range(10)])

    # create table view
    table = QTableView()

    # set parameters
    table.setModel(model)
    table.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
    table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ContiguousSelection)
    table.setMouseTracking(True)

    # show
    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As for overriding the `data` method for the model: `data` method is responsible for returning many different values depending on the `role` that view asks. You are always returning `"test"` for all of them. That is, to say the least, *bad*. If you want to create your own models, you should at least read about how models/views work in Qt. Official docs have [a nice section](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html) about it. You can also find some decent video tutorials in the web.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know about the `selectionModel`. That should fix that problem. I know the sub classes weren't required. they were just a simplified version of the structure I am actually using (and using "test" was again just a simplified example to show what causes my confusion - I thought that would have been obvious). Whilst I am fairly new to model/view programming I have read about it and could not find the answer for this particular issue. I will read it again.

Comment: @FrankRueter: Have a look at the [possible roles](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) for an item. This includes a `CheckStateRole`. Returning a `string` for this role is invalid. View interprets this as well as it can, which turns out to be: "Hey, this item has an unchecked check box". Similar for other roles. And quite possibly there are several undocumented internal roles where returning a `string` would do unpredictable things. In the end, you get a sort of _broken_ model.

Comment: I see, thank you. I thought using a string was the simplest scenario. Will do some more reading to get it right. I basically need strings in all cells to represent the item and return the full data through the selected row (each row represents a data object with various attributes which I need to handle). Thanks for your help!